# Symfony: violation not showing at correct field as property-path seems to be set incorrectly

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony 6.2 project and I build a form that frequently requires types that allow adding and deleting items from lists. So I build an abstract type `AbstractSimpleArrayType` which contains the following build method:

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $entryOptions = array_merge($this->getEntryOptions($options), [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'f-listItemBox'],
        ]);

        if (!empty($this->getDataClassName())) {
            $entryOptions = array_merge($entryOptions, ['data_class' => $this->getDataClassName(),]);
        }

        $builder
            ->add('items', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => $this->getEntryTypeClassname(),
                'entry_options' => $entryOptions,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
            ])
        ;

        $builder->setDataMapper($this);
    }
```

Now I wanted to write a custom validator for one of this class's inheritors.

My validate method (inside a validator-class `AssertFunderData`) looks like this (it does nothing useful yet, it served just for me to play around):

```php
    public function validate(mixed $value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof FunderData) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Value must be instance of FunderData");
        }
        $this->context->buildViolation('The value is not valid.')
            ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $value->getName())
            ->atPath('name')
            ->addViolation();
    }
```

and is being used in my entity like this:

```php
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::JSON, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\All([
        new AssertFunderData,
    ])]
    private ?array $funderData = [];
```

I have a very simple class `FunderData` that is basically just a couple string-properties and getters/setters (among others a "name"-property as above snippet already suggests). I do also have a corresponding `FunderDataType` to define my single forms representing one dataset of funder-data within the list where I can add and remove funder-data-sets.

But when I submit the form the validation error is being shown at the top of the entire form and not at the appropriate `name`-field.

I tried to do some digging to understand this but I fail. I feel like the problem lies somewhere in this:

when I look into the violations via the symfony debug toolbar I can see that the actual path that is build for this violation is `data.funderData[1].name`.

In my understanding it should be `data.funderData.items[1].name`.

Is that correct? If so, how can I fix this?

PS: I also checked in the generated html which `id` and `name`-attributes have been generated by the form system and it turns out they also contain the `items`-part as expected.

UPDATE: by now I am a bit further down the road. It is indeed a pathing issue. I was able to make it work by putting it in an `#[Assert\Callback]` on the level of my entity which means the context is a different one and I can work myself upward to the field in question.
I got a syntactic error in my assumption above though. Correct was
`funderData[items][1].name`.
So it is indeed a path-issue. The question remains how to make this work from within a validator. I feel this would be more elegant than using `#[Assert\Callback]`.

Comment: Where is the constraint added? Can't see it in your example...

Comment: Hello! It's used via attribute within my entity. I added the respective lines to my question.

Comment: Your `atPath('name')` seems to be wrong, try removing it completely or setting it to `funderData`